# Pagination of Custom Post Types not Changing Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have a custom post type, jobs, being displayed on an external page using WP_Query() - the query itself is working fine.

However when I try to paginate the results, the older/newer links show up, but when I click on them, the content doesn't change - ie the page 'number' changes in the URL & the page reloads, but the posts don't move on.

I've tried using Wordpress' default next_posts_link & previous_posts_link and also with the wp_pagenavi plugin. In the code below I'm using wp_pagenavi .

Here's my code:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $params = 
        array(  'post_type'          => 'job', 
            'post_status'        => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page'     => 3,
             'paged'=>$paged
        );

        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();


        $wp_query->query($params); ?>

  <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){ wp_pagenavi(); } ?>

  <?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

// doing things with the post

 <?php endwhile; endif ?>
 <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; wp_reset_query() ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated it - this is driving me up the wall! ^_^

Comment: How many posts do you have in total?

Comment: 10 - I wish it was that simple ^_^

Answer (score 0):

A problem with a custom query is that the posts_per_page resets before the page loads. So if you got 10 posts, than you only have one page, because the default posts_per_page is 10. If you have 11 posts than you will see the second page, but not beyond that.

Solution for this is changing your posts_per_page settings in the back-end: Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most > 3. But this will change all archive page settings. Quick fix for this is adding

```
<?php global $query_string; query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
```

at the top of your archive templates where you want the default posts_per_page.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be with the way you are using the global variable. Your code is manipulating the global $wp_query variable, which might be causing unexpected behavior. Instead of overwriting $wp_query, consider using a custom query variable.
-OR-
Implement Custom Query for Pagination:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$params = array(
    'post_type' => 'job', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$job_query = new WP_Query($params);

if ($job_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($job_query->have_posts()) : $job_query->the_post();
        // Display your posts here
    endwhile;

    // Pagination
    if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
        wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $job_query));
    }

    wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset post data after the custom query
else : 
    echo 'No jobs found';
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>` instead of `<?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){ wp_pagenavi(); } ?>` and if it is not working, try to add this code snippet

```
/**
 * Custom Pagination
 */
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

    if (empty($pagerange)) {
        $pagerange = 5;
    }

    /**
     * This first part of our function is a fallback
     * for custom pagination inside a regular loop that
     * uses the global $paged and global $wp_query variables.
     *
     * It's good because we can now override default pagination
     * in our theme, and use this function in default quries
     * and custom queries.
     */
    global $paged;
    if (empty($paged)) {
        $paged = 1;
    }
    if ($numpages == '') {
        global $wp_query;
        $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$numpages) {
            $numpages = 1;
        }
    }


    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    $pages = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $numpages,
        'prev_next' => false,
        'type'  => 'array',
        'prev_next'   => TRUE,
        'prev_text'    => __('<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i>'),
        'next_text'    => __('<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>'),
    ) );
    if( is_array( $pages ) ) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            echo "<li>$page</li>";
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

}
```

in your function.php
and this code

```
<?php
  if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
    custom_pagination($the_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
  }
?>
```

in a template file where you like to have the pagination.